# sum colum values where distinct other column

Tags: mysql

I ran this query:

```
SELECT
  billed_currency,
  sum(billed_total_price) as sum
FROM
  invoice
WHERE
  account_id = 91863
```

And I got this results:

```
72012
```

This is what the table values look like that are being summed

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfhrf.png)

Rows 3,4 have the same stripe_invoice_id.

I need to only sum the values of the invoices where the stripe_invoice_id is not repeated, therefore the query must return the value 48012

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

If rows where `stripe_invoice_id` is duplicated also have the `billed_price` duplicated, and you want to sum it only once, you cand use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT stripe_invoice_id, billed_total_price
FROM invoice
WHERE account_id = 91863
```

and you can use this as a subquery:

```
SELECT stripe_invoice_id, SUM(billed_total_price)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT stripe_invoice_id, billed_total_price
  FROM invoice
  WHERE account_id = 91863
) s
GROUP BY stripe_invoice_id
```

Comment: And if not, the OP has to pick his poison and can either rewrite the DB/schema to fix the issue or use a GROUP_BY with LIMIT combination to pick n'th entries (or just the first) to hack around the issue.